# Change Animation Cocos2d

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have some question about Animation;
I have class with animation;

```
@interface Player : CCNode{

    CCSprite *_player;
    CCSpriteBatchNode *spriteSheet;
    CCAction *walkAction;
    CCAnimation *walkAnim;


    int playerSpeed;
    int xPos;
    int yPos;
    int state;
    int currentAnim;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) CCSprite *_player;



-(id)init {

    if( (self=[super init] )) {

        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"duckAnimDown.plist"];
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"DuckAnimTurn.plist"];
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"duckAnimUp.plist"];



        currentAnim = 0;
        state = 0;
        [self chekState];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)setState:(int)st {

    state = st;
    [self chekState];
}
-(void)chekState{


    [self stopAllActions];
    walkAnim = nil;


    if (state == 1 && currentAnim != state) {
        [spriteSheet removeChild:_player cleanup:YES];
        spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"duckAnimDown.png"];
        NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 12 ; ++i) {
            [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"duck_down%d.png", i]]];
        }
        walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.04f];//0.06
        _player = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"duck_down1.png"];
        walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];

    }
    if (state == 2 && currentAnim != state) {
        [spriteSheet removeChild:_player cleanup:YES];
        spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"DuckAnimTurn.png"];
        NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10 ; ++i) {
            [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"duck_turn%d.png", i]]];
        }
        walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.04f];//0.06
        _player = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"duck_turn1.png"];
        walkAction = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO];

    }
    if (state == 3 && currentAnim != state) {

        [spriteSheet removeChild:_player cleanup:YES];
        spriteSheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"duckAnimUp.png"];
        NSMutableArray *walkAnimFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

        for (int i = 1; i <= 13 ; ++i) {
            [walkAnimFrames addObject:[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"duck_up%d.png", i]]];
        }
        walkAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames:walkAnimFrames delay:0.04f];//0.06
        _player = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"duck_up1.png"];
        walkAction = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:[CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:walkAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO]];

    }
    if (currentAnim != state) {
        [_player runAction:walkAction];
        [spriteSheet addChild:_player];
        [self addChild:spriteSheet];
        currentAnim = state;
    }



}
```

I use this class in GameplayScene;

```
duckSprite = [Player node];
```

To change animation i call: `[duckSprite setState:2];`

It's ok, but when i change animation FPS are very low 20 - 25;
What is wrong in my code?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the problem is that you are doing too much things in your checkState method.
You can move almost all of it to the init method and then just call runAction for the appropriate animation.

Also you should probably use just one sprite sheet for all the animations. This way you won't need to reload the player sprite every time the animation changes.

Here is a [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/1271/how-to-use-animations-and-sprite-sheets-in-cocos2d) which explains everything nicely.